# Conversion de date a character

Tags: genexus

Alguien que me pueda ayudar quiero convertir este dato de tipo date a caracter le he intentado con CTOD pero no me sirve no se visualiza

```
&ClienteDeudas.CliDeudasFechaUltimoPago=CtoD(&RDEP_XLS.Cells(&fila,15).Text)
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el valor que tienes en la fila &fila, columna 15 del Excel? ¿De qué tipo es CliDeudasFechaUltimoPago?

Answer (score 0):

&FechaString = &RDEP_XLS.Cells(&fila,15).Text // aaaa/mm/dd

&Ano = &FechaString.Subtring(1,4).toNumeric()

&Mes = &FechaString.Subtring(6,2).toNumeric()

&Dia = &FechaString.Subtring(9,2).toNumeric()

&ClienteDeudas.CliDeudasFechaUltimoPago = Date.New(&ano,&mes,&dia)

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo estás intentando de convertirlo de Character a Date, y estás utilizando ExcelDocument. Probaste directamente con &RDEP_XLS.Cells(&fila,15).Date ?

Answer (score 0):

CtoD convierte caracter a Date. Para convertir de Date a Character es .ToString() o .ToFormattedString().
De todos modos, si formulaste mal la pregunta y quieres convertir de character a date, debes asegurarte de que el texto que lees tiene un formato fecha, y que sea compatible con tu configuración. Recuerda que se puede configrar para que sea día/mes/año o mes/día/año